# FFMpeg Sound Lost When Short Overlay Video Ends

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing

I am creating a video file that is 36 seconds long. It is made of three .mp4 files. One video file is the background and the other two videos are overlays. One of the overlay videos ends about 26 seconds into the video.

**Problem:** When the overlay ends at 26 seconds into the video, the overlay video remains on the screen paused and the **audio** for the **other two videos is lost**. *There is 10 seconds of dead air.*

It would be preferable if the video for the overlay was removed when it ended. However, the most important thing is it ending should not stop the audio for the other two videos.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel fatal \
    -itsoffset 0.401 -i 4609_segment_1_remote_0.mp4 \
    -itsoffset 0.304 -i 4609_segment_1_remote_1.mp4 \
    -i 4609_segment_1_local_0.mp4 \
    -filter_complex " \
        [1:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[rem1]; \
        [2:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[loc0]; \
        [0:v]transpose=1[rotate1]; \
        [rotate1][loc0]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[rem0]; \
        [rem0][rem1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-180:main_h-overlay_h-10[rem1]; \
        [0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3[a]" \
    -map "[rem1]" -map "[a]" -ac 3 -vcodec libx264 \
    -ar 44100 -strict -2 -acodec aac 4609_segment_1.mp4
```

Input File [0]: 4609_segment_1_remote_0.mp4
Alias: [0:v], [rem0], rotate1]
Duration: 00:00:35.58
Dimensions: 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3]
Starts: 0.401 seconds
Video is Rotated 90 degrees clockwise
Background Video

Input File [1]: 4609_segment_1_remote_1.mp4
Alias: [1:v], [rem1]
Duration: 00:00:25.14
Dimensions: 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3]
Starts: 0.304 seconds
Overlay: 180 px from right, 10 px from bottom

Input File [2]: 4609_segment_1_local_0.mp4
Alias:  [2:v], [loc0]
Duration: 00:00:34.98
Dimensions: 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3]
Starts: Immediately
Overlay: 10 px from right, 10 px from bottom

The result is a video 480x640. Video lasts 36 seconds. Audio lasts 26 seconds. There are two overlayed videos in the bottom right corner of the video.

Comment: `-strict -2` is not needed anymore. (Used to be required for `aac` as audio codec but it's now considered stable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loglevel fatal \
    -itsoffset 0.401 -i 4609_segment_1_remote_0.mp4 \
    -itsoffset 0.304 -i 4609_segment_1_remote_1.mp4 \
    -i 4609_segment_1_local_0.mp4 \
    -filter_complex " \
        [1:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[rem1]; \
        [2:v]scale=iw/4:-1:flags=lanczos[loc0]; \
        [0:v]transpose=1[rotate1]; \
        [rotate1][loc0]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[rem0]; \
        [rem0][rem1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-180:main_h-overlay_h-10:eof_action=pass[rem1]; \
        [1:a]apad[1a];[2:a]apad[2a]; \
        [0:a][1a][2a]amerge=inputs=3[a]" \
    -map "[rem1]" -map "[a]" -ac 3 -vcodec libx264 \
    -ar 44100 -strict -2 -acodec aac 4609_segment_1.mp4
```

`amerge` terminates with the shortest input, so the remedy is to indefinitely extend all inputs except one, which decides output audio length.

`eof_action=pass` will clear out the overlay once the secondary stream ends.